# Why are actor messages serializable?

Tags: java, scala, akka

Reading "http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/remoting.html" it states " all messages sent over the wire must be serializable" which in turn requires all messages sent to actor's are serializable. Why is it required that the actor be serializable ?

Is the reason that messages are sent between actors using serialization and deserialization ? Reason messages are sent/received using serialization is that potentially message could be sent to actors that reside on different JVM's ?

Comment: Well, yes, that's certainly one reason.

Comment: The core concept of Actors is seamlessly distributable computing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Messages don't technically need to be serializable unless they are actually sent across a process boundary. Best practice is that all messages should be serializable in order to maintain location transparency.

To enforce serializability for testing purposes, you can use the configuration `akka.actor.serialize-messages=on`, which will cause akka to always attempt to serialize messages even when sent locally.

Comment: "across a process boundary" , by this are you referring to a message originating from a different jvm than where the message originated

Comment: A message sent from an actor in one JVM to an actor in another JVM. Since the messages are sent over a socket, they need to be serialized into bytes in the sender's process (JVM) and then deserialized back to the message object in the receiver's process (JVM).